# What is a "dump" (both software-wise and hardware-wise)

Tags: security, architecture, hardware

"Dump". This is one of the most cliché words I've heard among hardcore programmers and hackers, and yet, I never knew what it means. I found it almost everywhere that center around low-level software and digital hardware. They say something like "dumping a file", "dump a CPU", "dump a memory", and so on. What is it, and how is this feat usually performed?

Comment: Originally from this word: http://catb.org/jargon/html/C/core-dump.html , current (general) use resembles "take contents of X and output them" (dump a CPU? CPU *state*, perhaps?).

Comment: @Piskvor: Not quite. A core dump is a very specific dump. The term *core dump* is UNIX jargon, though, for *process dump*.

Comment: @DarkDust: "Originally", and what you are saying is essentially that JF entry :)

Comment: @Piskvor: The point is 'Core dump' isn't the original use. People were dumping other things before they dumped core. Hmmm.... dump is a fun word.... dump, dump, dump, dump!

Comment: @Paul S: Sure they were (and are), but that's, um, slightly off-topic ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *dump* is data taken from a storage medium, AS-IS, i.e. unedited.

For example, [core dump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) is a the content of the recorded state of the core from a specified time.

In Unix, [Dump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dump_%28program%29) is a software to backup file systems.

In essence, dump is a content taken from a storage medium (that contains the all state of the medium), that is used mostly for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 8):

In programming, to dump something means to get its content. For example, if one says you *need to dump memory at address XY* it means to query the content of the memory at the given address and store it somewhere for analysis (the result is then called a *memory dump*).

Answer (score 1):

[Core Dump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump):

> In computing, a core dump (more properly a memory dump or storage dump) consists of the recorded state of the working memory of a computer program at a specific time, generally when the program has terminated abnormally (crashed).[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) The name comes from the days when magnetic core memory was used, before the introduction of semiconductor memory; the name has remained established in systems inspired by UNIX long after the technology had faded from use. In practice, other key pieces ...

Comment: What is wrong with that? A dump is something else than recorded memory or recorded state?

Comment: Probably that the question was about the verb 'to dump' rather than the noun 'a dump' of which 'a core dump' is only a specific example. Harsh to down vote though.

Comment: Yeah. Now tell me what the big difference is to the accepted answer. I think the wiki entry is a good explanation. So what the downvote for?

Answer (score 0):

In it's large meaning, it represents the state of a running program(process) in a medium storage.